# Terraform Alerts for Azure Functions

Tags: azure, terraform, azure-functions

I am trying to research if it is possible to create alerts for azure functions via terraform.

My goal is to create a general rule that can be setup for on going functions that would alert us if an automated/timed function fails for x amount of times

Comment: Kindly share your code, what you have tried?

Answer (score 2):

**I tried to reproduce the same in my environment to create the Alerts in Function app using Terraform:**

**Terraform code.**

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "thejesh-rg" {
  name     = "Thejesh-RG-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}
resource "azurerm_storage_account" "thejeshstorage" {
  name                     = "thejeshstorageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_service_plan" "thejeshsp" {
  name                = "thejeshsp-app-service-plan"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.location
  os_type             = "Linux"
  sku_name            = "P1v2"
}

resource "azurerm_linux_function_app" "thejesh" {
  name                = "thejesh-linux-function-app"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.name
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.location

  storage_account_name       = azurerm_storage_account.thejeshstorage.name
  storage_account_access_key = azurerm_storage_account.thejeshstorage.primary_access_key
  service_plan_id            = azurerm_service_plan.thejeshsp.id

  site_config {}
}


resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "actiongroup" {
  name                = "thejesh-actiongroup"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.name
  short_name          = "exampleact"
  email_receiver{
  email_address = "Email-ID"
  name          = "sendtoadmin"
  }
}
resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "metrics" {
  name                = "theja-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.thejesh-rg.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_linux_function_app.thejesh.id]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when Transactions count is greater than 1."
  
  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Web/sites"
    metric_name      = "Requests"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold         = "1"
    }
    action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.actiongroup.id
  }
  }
```

**Terraform Plan:**

[image]

**Terraform Apply**

[image]

Once ran the code resources are created.

[image]

**Alert notification**.

[image]

**Successfully received email.**

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Yes it's possible. [See the documentation here](https://registry.terraform.io/providers/hashicorp/azurerm/latest/docs/resources/monitor_metric_alert).

Sample taken from the docs is creating a metric alert:

```
resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "example-resources"
  location = "West Europe"
}

resource "azurerm_storage_account" "to_monitor" {
  name                     = "examplestorageaccount"
  resource_group_name      = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  location                 = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  account_tier             = "Standard"
  account_replication_type = "LRS"
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_action_group" "main" {
  name                = "example-actiongroup"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  short_name          = "exampleact"

  webhook_receiver {
    name        = "callmyapi"
    service_uri = "http://example.com/alert"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_monitor_metric_alert" "example" {
  name                = "example-metricalert"
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  scopes              = [azurerm_storage_account.to_monitor.id]
  description         = "Action will be triggered when Transactions count is greater than 50."

  criteria {
    metric_namespace = "Microsoft.Storage/storageAccounts"
    metric_name      = "Transactions"
    aggregation      = "Total"
    operator         = "GreaterThan"
    threshold        = 50

    dimension {
      name     = "ApiName"
      operator = "Include"
      values   = ["*"]
    }
  }

  action {
    action_group_id = azurerm_monitor_action_group.main.id
  }
}
```